# How to mock the flutter universal html package

Tags: flutter-test, flutter-mockito

I am using this library to use the `html.window.open()` method in my code, but I'm not able to mock it for my tests. I have imported the lib like this `import "package:universal_html/html.dart" as html;` in the code. My test tries to verify (using mockito) whether this method was called and also verify what argument was used.
Please help! Thanks :)